# How prove $PE + PF + PG + PH < 1$ in regular tetrahedron?

Tags: geometry

Point $P$ lies inside regular tetrahedron $ABCD$ with edge 1. Lines $AP, BP, CP, DP$ respectively cut $BCD, CDA, DAB, ABC$ in points $E, F, G, H$. How prove $PE + PF + PG + PH < 1$? I have no idea how to do this, can this be proved with simple geometry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me show you how a 2D analogue of this problem can be solved. It is then relatively easy to translate the proof into original problem.

The problem at hand is now:

> Point $P$ lies inside an equilateral triangle $ABC$ with edge length $1$. Lines $AP,BP,CP$ respectively cut $BC,CA,AB$ in points $D,E,F$. Prove $PD+PE+PF<1$.

We will need a simple geometric lemma, proof of which I leave to you:

> If $XYZ$ is equilateral, $W$ lies on $YZ$ then $XW<XY$.

Now let's draw three lines parallel to the sides through $P$. After marking the segments of equal length with the same color (except for black ones, these might be different), we get the following picture:

[image]

Using the lemma, $PD$ is shorter than green segments, $PE$ is shorter than red segments and $PF$ is shorter than blue segments, so $PD+PE+PF$ is less than sum of lengths of green, red and blue segments. But this sum is exactly the length of the side of the triangle, which is $1$.